# loop through php arrayray with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, loops

I have a php array:

```
print_r($names);
```

output:

```
Array ( [adam] => adam [John] => John [Clair] => Clair [Sue] => Sue)
```

I want to loop through the array with jquery/javascript.

I set the javascript variable equal to that of the PHP array:

```
var jnames="<?php print($names); ?>";
```

How can I loop through the array jnames?

```
for(var i=0; i < jnames.length; i++)
  {
    alert(jnames[i]);
  }
```

This simply returns A, then R, then R, then A, then Y for array.

How can I get this to return the proper value of the array? being adam, john, clair etc.

Thanks.

Comment: `json_encode` to object.

Comment: You are outputting the word "Array" since `print()` will echo the type of an variable if its not a string, float, or integer. You need to json encode the $names variable prior to assigning it to jnames and then parse it using JSON.parse()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
var jnames=<?php print(json_encode($names)); ?>;
```

Or simply

```
var jnames=<?=json_encode($names) ?>;
```

which is usually supported

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Half of programming is learning what a language can do. In this case php has a function for what you are looking for: https://www.php.net/json_encode

`var jnames = <?php echo json_encode($names); ?>;`